# bluetooth adapter action not found

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I am registering  broad cast receiver statically in the manifest file, and I wanted to receive notifications when the connection is enabled. I refered to android developers website [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)

and it says that I have to use the following:

```
 Constant Value: "android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE"
```

and in my manifest file, I added the following, but there is nothing called REQUEST_ENABLE:

```
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.XXXX" >
```

please let me know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED if you want to know when bluetooth adapter is turned on/off.

Few more questions for you:
1. Can you try building with this permission defined (even with the error) and show your code as well as the errors? 
2. Are you using android studio, Eclipse?
3. What is your min/target/compile sdk versions (or project build target in Eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive notifications when it's connected.you should use:

```
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED"/>
```

If you want to receive the status about turning/turned on/off,you should use:

```
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.extra.STATE"/>
```